# Downloading the last 24 records sorted by the hour

Tags: php, mysql

I sorry for my bad English.
I have a problem I can't deal with for a few days.
I want to create a graph showing active users for the last 24 hours. I have only a problem with the MySQL query. My current query:

```
SELECT SUM(players) FROM servers_players WHERE account_id = 1
```

Would anyone help me create a query that will return:
- the last 24 records (for a 24-hour chart) counted from the current hour to the same hour from the previous day.
I ask kindly :)

//edit:
I hold the hour in timestamp and hour
[screen_db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWLUn.png)

Comment: Show the ddl please

Comment: Where are you storing the timestamp responsible for activity?

Comment: share with us your table schema so someone can assist you.

Comment: Should be something like `... WHERE <datetime_column> BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW()`  If you use a unix timestamp column `... WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(<unix_timestamp_column>) BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW()`.. The last one can't use a index..

Comment: Are you sure you want to bring back ONLY 24 records? You can do that with LIMIT 24; but not sure why you would do that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT *
FROM servers_players
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW()
```